# how to generate the LLVM IR when nest basicblock in LLVM

Tags: llvm

There is a function basicblock  A,another block in the inside of  block  A ,how to generate the LLVM IR.For example:

```
int fun()
{/*block A*/
  int i=0;
  {/*block B*/
    int i=1
    printf("i in block B is %d\n",i);
  }
  printf("i in block A is %d\n",i);
 }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Basic blocks can't be nested. Please clarify what you mean by that.

Comment: You're confusing higher-level lexical scopes with basic blocks, as sepp2k noted basic blocks can't be nested.

Answer (score 4):

Your blocks `A` and `B` aren't basic blocks, they're just blocks. C (or whichever language this is) does not have a concept of basic blocks - LLVM does.

Basic blocks in LLVM do not have to (and often don't) correspond to blocks in the source language. Basically a basic block is just a unit of code, such that you never jump into or out of the middle of it. You only jump to the beginning of the block and only jump from its end.

Blocks in source languages can serve many purposes. Sometimes they're used as part of control flow statements - sometimes  they're not. And sometimes you can have control flow without blocks. For example, in many languages, loops and `if` statements can be used with a single statement body that is not a compound statement (e.g. `if (condition) return;` - no block here, but still control flow). Likewise `switch` statements generally don't have a block for each case and then there's of course `goto`.

So when there's control flow without blocks, the generated program will contain more basic blocks than the source program contained blocks. And in the opposite case where there are blocks without control flow, the generated program will contain less basic blocks.

In your example, the function `fun` contains no control flow other than the implicit return at the end of the function. Therefore you should only generate a single basic block for it.

Comment: Hi, does your answer reference any LLVM document ? If yes, would you please provide them ?

Comment: @linrongbin No, my answer does not contain any references to the LLVM docs. Are you saying it should? If so, which part?